# Как задать transition флексу?

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Есть такой код, как при наведение сделать чтобы плавно переходило в flex-direction column;

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  transition: all 3s easy-in;
}

.avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.flex:hover {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class=“flex”>
  <span class=“avatar”></span>
  <div class=“text”>text</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147392/discussion-on-question-by-express---transition-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.